# Using thread-safe ConcurrentDictionary collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I've a such function which uses unthread-safe collection List, also to be thread-safe it uses lock-operator:

```
public void ShowData(ref DataGridView dmRequests, ref DataGridView URL, ref DataGridView dmData, ref DataGridView errorCodes)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> urlReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>(); 
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmDataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> errCodesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();

    lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
    {
        dmReqList = m_logStruct.domainName.ToList();
    }
    lock(m_logStruct.URL)
    {
        urlReqList = m_logStruct.URL.ToList();
    }
    lock(m_logStruct.domainData)
    {
        dmDataList = m_logStruct.domainData.ToList();
    }
    lock(m_logStruct.errorCodes)
    {
        errCodesList = m_logStruct.errorCodes.ToList();
    }

    dmRequests.DataSource = dmReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
    URL.DataSource = urlReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
    dmData.DataSource = dmDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
    errorCodes.DataSource = errCodesList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
}
```

I want to convert it to do it lock-free. To do it I've used in this function ConcurrentDictionary collection instead of List  collection, so my function begin look so:

```
public void ShowData(ref DataGridView dmRequests, ref DataGridView URL, ref DataGridView dmData, ref DataGridView errorCodes)
{
    try
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> dmReqList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> urlReqList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> dmDataList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> errCodesList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();

        dmReqList = m_logStruct.domainName;
        urlReqList = m_logStruct.URL;
        dmDataList = m_logStruct.domainData;
        errCodesList = m_logStruct.errorCodes;

        dmRequests.DataSource = dmReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
        URL.DataSource = urlReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();//I get error here: Index is out of range                
        dmData.DataSource = dmDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();              
        errorCodes.DataSource = errCodesList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e + " Something bad has been occurred here!");
    }

}
```

But in this function I begin get error(Index is out of range). How to use thread-safe collection(ConcurrentDictionary) correctly? How to fix my error?

Comment: You declare new dictionaries but then immedatly overwrite them. you can get rid of all of your `new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();` in the function, they do not do anything for you.

Comment: Your sample shows code that can't expose variables to multiple threads (all local variables) - consider updating your code to actually show how something like `errCodesList` can be accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: Side note: please consider cutting down samples to just one set of collections - having 4 almost identical sections in each function does not provide any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to be concurrent if you're replacing the variable where you're storing the list.  You need to use the concurrent methods that it provides.  See the examples in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use `TryAdd`, `TryUpdate`, `TryRemove` or `AddOrUpdate` in order to add to the list or update the list so rather than:

```
dmReqList = m_logStruct.domainName;
```

Do something like:

```
foreach (var item in m_logStruct.domainName)
{
    dmReqList.TryAdd(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

**UPDATE:**  As pointed out by Alexei, you're defining the dmReqList locally.  This means that you're getting no benefit from it being a ConcurrentDictionary because no other thread could access it anyway. Also, you imply from your original example that m_logStruct is accessible via other threads because you applied the lock to it.  If the implication is correct, then that is what needs to be a ConcurrentDictionary.  So, your code would need to look more like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong> _domainNames = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ulong>();

public void ShowData(ref DataGridView dmRequests)
{
    dmRequests.DataSource = _domainNames.OrderBy(x => x.Key);  //Set the current values of the dictionary to the grid.
}

public void MultiThreadedMethod()
{
    _domainNames.TryAdd(someKey, someValue);  //Access the dictionary from multiple threads.
}
```

Comment: Note that while somewhat answering the question on how to use `ConcurrentDictionary` this suggestion allows access to `m_logStruct` from multiple threads and thus completely not thread safe. Using `ConcurrentDictionary` for local variables that are not visible to any other thread does not make code any more "thread safe" compared to regular list/dictionary.

Comment: The OP didn't provide the definition for m_logStruct, but based on the convention, we can assume this is a private global variable.  True, if m_logStruct is accessible to multiple threads that change it, it's "possibly" not completely thread safe, but we just have to assume that the OP already knows that since he isn't worried about access to m_logStruct, but rather dmReqList.  Also, dmReqList is not a local variable.  If you look at the OP's method definition, he is passing that into the method by reference.

Comment: "dmReqList is not a local variable" - what it is than? Note that original code was locking on `lock (m_logStruct.domainName)` so looks like `m_logStruct` and its fields need protection... (Note samples provided are somewhat random code - i.e. passing all parameters by ref or locking on fields instead of separate objects - so it *may* mean OP does not care much about that particular code and just interested in tips on using `ConcurrentDictionary`)

Comment: Oh, you're right about dmReqList.  I was reading it wrong.  I will update my answer which will also address your other statement.